# Dictionary of Cells

Tags: excel, dictionary, vba

I'm trying to create a dictionary where the R1C1 Formula is the key and the cell is the item but am having trouble casting the item when it is retrieved from the dictionary.  So far I have the following code that appears to create the dictionary just fine:

```
Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim c As Range

Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
  If Not dict.Exists(c.FormulaR1C1) Then dict.Item(c.FormulaR1C1) = c
Next c
```

The problem I'm having is when trying to access the items in the dictionary, I can't seem to figure out how to cast the Item as a Range/Cell.  I tried the following but get a Runtime Error '424': Object Required

```
Dim r As Range
Dim k As Variant

For Each k In dict.Keys
  Set r = dict.Item(k)
Next k
```

Also tried just treating the item as a range and calling things .Formula property:

```
Range("A1").value = "'" & dict.Item(k).Formula
```

Tried setting it to the "object" as follows:

```
Set r = dict.Item(k).Object
```

None of of which works.  What is the right way to use a dictionary where the item is an object rather than just a string (or is that not possible)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of points:

1. If you want to add a `Range` object to the dictionary item, you have to use the `Set` keyword when you're adding it to the dictionary, not when you're retrieving it.
2. The `FormulaR1C1` of the cell may *not* be the best key to use. The reason is that, presuming you have the same formula in a series of cells, the key will only be added once. This may be the behavior you desire, and if so, ignore this point. If not, you may need to consider a different key.

See the below code. To demonstrate that I'm retrieving a cell from the dictionary, I just colored the cell. Obviously, change that to suit your needs.

```
Sub AddRangesTdictionary()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim c As Range

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each c In Range("B1:B4")
        If Not dict.Exists(c.FormulaR1C1) Then
            Set dict.Item(c.FormulaR1C1) = c
        End If
    Next c

    For Each k In dict.Keys
        dict.Item(k).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: That's perfect!  the `Set dict.Item(k) = c` did the trick!  Why is it always something so obvious.

For #2, I'm using the `FormulaR1C1` specifically to avoid duplicate entries for "like" formulas.  For the analysis I'm doing, if you're referencing B2 from C2 or F44 from G44 they're the "same."  I'm only interested if all of a sudden you're referencing A6 from C6 instead of B6.  As you mentioned, it's helping to identify instances where an different formula is added to the mix.

Thank you for the help!